# Restoring multiple text fields and labels in one view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uisegmentedcontrol, state-restoration

I have a view controller containing 2 text fields, 2 segmented controls and a few labels which display time stamps set by the user using `UIButtons`. I would like to be able to restore any user set values for these items upon quit / restart, as well as when going back to my main menu `view controller`, which is a `navigation controller`. Using the following code, I am able to restore one of the text fields on background / terminate / restart, but I am unsure as to how to accomplish this for my other text field or the time stamp labels and segmented controls. I have tried to duplicate the restoration code with changes for the text field name and the `@"UnsavedText"` string with no luck.

Furthermore, whenever I go back to the main menu using the back button in the navigation bar, I lose all of my data from all fields.

Here is the code in my delegate, opting in to state restoration:

```
// Sets RESTORATION
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Here is the relevant code in my view controller to restore the one text field. I am including my `viewDidLoad` code with state initialization in case that is somehow part of the problem:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Updates time on currentTimeLabel
    [self updateTime];

    // Sets initial button states
    [self setInitialState];

    // Sets UITextField delegate
    self.startLevel.delegate = self;
    self.stopLevel.delegate = self;
    // initializes basic values for segmented controls
    bigTank = YES;
    startFractions = @"";
    stopFractions = @"";


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Restoration of text fields
-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    // start level text
    [coder encodeObject:_startLevel.text forKey:@"UnsavedText"];
    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

}

-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    // start level text
    _startLevel.text = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"UnsavedText"];
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

}



// Sets initial button and label states
- (void)setInitialState
{
    self.start.enabled = YES;
    self.stop.enabled = NO;
    self.calculate.enabled = NO;
    self.resume.enabled = NO;

    // Text for time labels reset
    _startTimeLabel.text = @"- -:- -:- -.- -";
    _stopTimeLabel.text = @"- -:- -:- -.- -";

    // Resets the minuteRateLabel
    _minuteRateLabel.text = @"--.--";

    // Resets the text fields to their initial state with the placeholder "inches" text
    [_startLevel setText:nil];
    [_stopLevel setText:nil];

    // Resets inch levels to EVEN
    [self.startFractionControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    [self.stopFractionControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    startFractions = @"";
    stopFractions = @"";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This is the code I tried per the suggestion:

My button click should ostensibly save the time stamp value:

```
- (IBAction)startButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss.SS"];
    _startTimeLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    UIButton *startButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    // Creates the start time stamp for use in the calculation
    startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    // sets button states
    startButton.enabled = NO;
    stop.enabled = YES;
    // Hides keypad on startButton click
    [self.startLevel resignFirstResponder];
    [self.stopLevel resignFirstResponder];

    // saves the value for restoration using user defaults
    NSDateFormatter *startTimeSave = formatter;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
     setObject:startTimeSave forKey:@"startTimeSaver"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your text values using user defaults. Here is a sample code snippet:

```
NSString *valueToBeSaved = @"someValue";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
setObject:valueToBeSaved forKey:@"preferenceName"];
```

And for retrieving your value later, use this:

```
NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
```

Comment: You can either put it in your controller, or you can create a separate class for this. You can refer to the following links : http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/70672-saving-a-value-user-defaults.html ,  http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Comment: Had to step away for a minute. Going to give it a shot right now. Will some variant of this work for my labels and segmented controls?

Comment: It will work for the values like text that you want to save. Might not work for the objective C objects.

Comment: It will work for the values like text and Bool values that you want to save. Might not work for all the objective C objects but might work for some properties

Comment: This is not working the way I have it set up. I am trying for one to save a time stamp grabbed using a button click. I am updating my OP to show the code.

Comment: What is it showing? Are you retrieving the saved value?

Comment: I was able to get this working by tweaking my original encode/decode code, and by working I mean the data sticks around for the text fields, the segmented controls, and the time labels on background / termination. What's odd it that when I run a calculation when I come back, I am getting INF as the result. Log is showing the correct values in the equation, but it returns infinity. Also, going back to the main menu erases all user data. Still need to figure that out.